# How can I make a Python script keep running after I close my shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssh, process

I've coded a Discord bot in Python. I have it hosted on a server that I use PuTTy to SSH into. Closing that terminal will obviously result in the bot ceasing to work. Does Python have a process management system that will allow me to keep a Python script running?

I'm running centOS.

Comment: What operating system is the server running?

Comment: This is more of a ssh question then a python question, you can use nohup

Comment: [Relevant.](https://pypi.org/project/python-daemon/)

Comment: If the server is running Linux, you can use nohup.
`nohup python myScript.py &`

Comment: Or start your bot in a tmux pane and then attach to that pane when you ssh into the server.

Comment: If you actually need to do this from within Python, you’re basically asking how to write a daemon. Assuming you’re on Unix/Linux, look for the Python daemon library on PyPI. But usually you don’t need this; you just need `nohup`, and you can find more details more easily on Super User, Server Fault, Unix, AskDifferent, AskUbuntu, etc. than Stack Overflow, because it’s more of a sysadmin question than a programming one.

Answer (score 0):

It depends about how much experience you have programming in python.
For example you could use [daemonize](https://daemonize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (which I personally prefer).
And this is the simplest example available (from the daemonize documentation)

```
from time import sleep
from daemonize import Daemonize

pid = "/tmp/test.pid"


def main():
    while True:
        sleep(5)

daemon = Daemonize(app="test_app", pid=pid, action=main)
daemon.start()
```

Another way to keep your script running, it could be install [screen](https://www.gnu.org/software/screen/).
Execute screen before executing your script and then detach the session using "Ctrl+a"+"d"

Comment: Thanks, `screen` seems to be a pretty good solution. Do you know if there's any way I can utilize screen so that this same Python script re-launches if the server happens to restart?

Comment: The easiest way to achieve this is to append the path of your script into /etc/rc.local